# JS Model Display Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the beginnings of a JavaScript Modal, although there is a big overflow error that occurs while it is open.

Code:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  document.querySelector('.tabcontent.open')?.classList.remove('open');
  document.getElementById(cityName).classList.add('open')

  document.querySelector('.tablinks.active')?.classList.remove('active');
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
}


modal.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('defaultOpen') && document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Modal Content */

#myModal {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  float: left;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */

.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
  /* this hides all tabs */
}

.tabcontent.open {
  display: block;
  /* show current tab */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>dtnhdrtytntnntfyndtmntfnytnrtbdrtbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tdrnbtrrdtrdtbtbdtdnbdrntdAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tndrntbtdbtrdtdrbfntyftnrgbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tbtryfbdtbyrdbfnyfnynydbrdbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>dtnhdrtytntnntfyndtmntfnytnrtbdrtbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tdrnbtrrdtrdtbtbdtdnbdrntdAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tndrntbtdbtrdtdrbfntyftnrgbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tbtryfbdtbyrdbfnyfnynydbrdbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>dtnhdrtytntnntfyndtmntfnytnrtbdrtbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tdrnbtrrdtrdtbtbdtdnbdrntdAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tndrntbtdbtrdtdrbfntyftnrgbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tbtryfbdtbyrdbfnyfnynydbrdbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>dtnhdrtytntnntfyndtmntfnytnrtbdrtbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tdrnbtrrdtrdtbtbdtdnbdrntdAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tndrntbtdbtrdtdrbfntyftnrgbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>
  <h2>tbtryfbdtbyrdbfnyfnynydbrdbAnimated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <h2 class="center">Vertical Tabs</h2>
    <p class="center">Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <p class="center">Some text in the Modal..</p>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'one')" id="defaultOpen">number 1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'two')">Number 2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'three')">number 3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'four')">number 4</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'five')">number 5</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'six')">number 6</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'seven')">number 7</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'eight')">number 8</button>
    </div>

    <div id="one" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">one</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">two</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="three" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">three</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="four" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">four</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="five" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">five</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="six" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">six</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="seven" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">seven</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="eight" class="tabcontent">
      <h3 class="center">eight</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

*** I have removed the lines below so it is easier to view, but it will be used in the final code. It only disables scrolling on the page. ***

> ```
>  window.onscroll = function () { window.scroll(0, 0); };
>  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
> ```

When the code is run, the tabs overflow the container. How would I make it so the tabs stay either (A) within the container, and have a scroll bar (So only the tabs scroll, not the page), or (B) have the entire container be longer, and then the ability to just scroll in the container (And not the page).

EDIT:
I just wanted to add some clarification. When this model opens, the scrolling and interactivity of the background is paused, so the user can only interact with the model. The model should look something like the image below, that's my final goal.

Final Goal:
[image: Final Goal]

Comment: You are giving your modal a fixed height of 70%. You should remove any height restrictions.

Comment: That actually makes it worse, setting it to "Auto" does not even work. Is there something else I should set it as?